# Stop execution in repetion structure. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, exception, message, execution

I need to stop the execution of a program in VB.net. Within a repeating structure the program checks whether a variable is true or false. When the variable is false I need to stop the program execution. I do not want to close the program but simply stop it. One way I found was raising an exception, but I would not want to display the error message to the user. What is the best way to do it ?

```
Do
  If myvariable=false then
  throw new exception... 'Silent exception
  end if
Loop until ….
```

Davis

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the program execution"? Stop it in the debugger? Or just exit the loop?

Comment: I'll put a buck on Return being the correct answer.

Comment: @Yatrix: He's better than VB.NET? What does that even mean? VB.NET has a `Return` keyword.

Comment: Whoops! Comment deleted to avoid further embarrassment. Been C#ing lately =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Based on below comment.

In that case I would use something like.

```
Do   
    If myvariable=false then   
        Return
    end if   
Loop until ….
```

---

I am really not sure what you are wanting to do.

You can close the application by using [`Application.Exit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.APPLICATION.EXIT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

If you want to be really abrupt you can call the [`End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wt87xba.aspx) Statement.

```
Terminates execution immediately.
```

and

> The End statement stops code execution abruptly, and does not invoke the Dispose or Finalize method, or any other Visual Basic code. Object references held by other programs are invalidated. If an End statement is encountered within a Try or Catch block, control does not pass to the corresponding Finally block.

You can use the [`Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6acc062s.aspx) Statement to suspend execution but it will invoke the debugger.

> If the Stop statement is encountered in code that is running outside of the integrated development environment (IDE), the debugger is invoked. This is true regardless of whether the code was compiled in debug or retail mode.

Or if you are just wanting to exit out of your `Do` Statement you can try this

```
Do   
    If myvariable=false then   
        Exit Do
    end if   
Loop until ….
```

Comment: My application is awaiting a response from an api of another application, and my program is running a iteration while the return of a function of the api is not a desired value. Due to various reasons may be I'll never get the expected return of the condition of repetition structure. So if the user see it's taking too long to get the expected return of function he can click a button ("STOP") that will make the program exit the repeat structure and stop without proceeding to the subsequents subs. I do not want the program to quit, but simply stops until the user click a button to start again.

Comment: @SammyDavis Most structures have a way to exit them like the `Exit Do` that I used above. What you could use is an `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function` or just plain `Return` depending on what type of Method that your Structure is located.

Comment: An alternative to the VB.NET-specific Stop keyword is to use the static System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() method which is supported by all .NET languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit a loop with an exit statement. Alternatively, you can use your method of throwing an exception and surround the loop in a Try/Catch block which catches that specific exception and ignores it.

Comment: Tks, I completed the initial post. See it again.

Comment: And what would be the point in throwing an exception just to catch and swallow it?

Comment: If, after the loop has exited, you need to test why it exited and act differently depending on whether it exited because the process completed or because the user canceled, throwing a UserCanceledException isn't necessarily a bad way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stop then you can use the Stop keyword. However, I'm not confident from your question that this is what you actually want as it has different outcomes depending on whether it's running as a exe or in the IDE.

Some more context to your question would be useful in finding the best answer for your problem.